# Finding the Total no of digits in each element of the list using maths.log10 function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following code but it is giving me an error.How should i fix this problem?.

```
import math
mylist=[3,4,12,34]
digits = int(math.log10(mylist))+1


Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "prog.py", line 3, in <module>  
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: `map(lambda v: int(math.log10(v))+1, mylist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a list containing the number of digits of each element in `my_list`.

```
from math import log10

my_list = [3, 4, 12, 34]
digits = [int(log10(n) + 1) for n in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a list to `log10()` function, and that's while it accepts a float. You can use a list comprehension to calculate the log for all items within the list:

```
>>> digits = [int(math.log10(i)) + 1 for i in mylist]
>>> digits
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
import math


def f(x):
    return int(math.log10(x)) + 1

mylist = [3, 4, 12, 34]
digits = []

for x in mylist:
    fx = f(x)
    print("f({0})={1}".format(x, fx))
    digits.append(fx)
```